# Is it possible to use Sharepoint 2007 without installing it?

Tags: windows-xp, sharepoint-2007

My company wants to buy Sharepoint 2007 and they asked me if I could give an opinion.

I've saw already a lot of videos and read e-books but would like to use it for a while, specially the integration with Sharepoint Designer 2007.

The only way to do that is installing it on a trial basis? Is there any other way? Any available public installation?

I only have an old 32-bit laptop with Windows XP.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest is to sign up for a 30-day trial of Microsoft's **[SharePoint Online Services](http://www.microsoft.com/online/sharepoint-online.mspx)**.

Note: They may only be offering v2010, check with a sales rep.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to create a Virtual Machine and install SharePoint as a single server install.  You would use the eval copy.  If you plan on actually licensing this install, do careful planning.  A single server install is not the correct option for future growth. Your older laptop may not handle this easily.  I would also suggest some of the MS online training and any books you can find.   Lots to learn.